# WLResourceRequest onSuccess throws error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am getting an error on `WLResourceRequest`'s onsuccess callback and the error is as below.

> com.sun.jdi.InternalException : Unexpected JDWP Error: 14 Cannot evaluate com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponse.toString()

why do we get this error? is there a way to skip this .

Code I used is

it works fine I get the response when I use 
**WLHttpResponseListener** instead of WLResponseListener.

wlResponse.getResponseText(); gives empty response.

```
 WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest("Actual server path here", GET);
      request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("IfAnyHeader", "here"));
    request.send(new ResponseListener());
 private class ResponseListener implements WLResponseListener {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {

            responseCode = wlResponse.getStatus();
            final String result = wlResponse.getResponseText();
      }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {

            responseCode = wlFailResponse.getStatus();
            final String result = wlFailResponse.getResponseText();
}
```

I get the error on onSuccess method... wlResponse.getResponseText(); is always empty.

Comment: Why not start by providing that code you've implemented?

Comment: I have edited the question please answer...

Comment: If you are able to give negative feed you should be also able to give solutions.

Comment: Do you think I just sit on my chair and wait for you to reply? You'll wait until an answer is possible to be provided. This is a community. If you don't want to wait, in a community, go ahead and open a support ticket.

Comment: It looks like you are waiting for my reply now... so fast reply..

Comment: And now I'm going home, because it's weekend here.

Comment: Please but don't give negative feeds just like that..

Comment: You received a -1 because you wrote a poor question without anything that could help debugging it. Now that you improved it you received a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this issue.

```
     request.send( new WLHttpResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        try {

    //                        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                            WLResponse wlResponse=new WLResponse(httpResponse);

                            int responseCode=wlResponse.getStatus();


                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
// used a function to convert reader to string
                            final String result = entityToString(reader);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(HttpResponse httpResponse, Exception e) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        try {



                            responseCode = new WLFailResponse(new WLResponse(httpResponse)).getStatus();

                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                            String result = entityToString(reader);

                        } catch (IOException eec) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

WLResponseListener supports WLClient.invokeProcedure.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-j2me/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLResponseListener.html

WLHTTPResponseListener supports sending WLResourceRequests
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLHttpResponseListener.html

Since you are using WLResourceRequest (best practice), this is the expected behavior.

Comment: If I am using WLHTTPResponseListener  I have question how do I get status code.. because WLHTTPResponseListener has HTTPResponse and httpResponse.getStatusline().getStatusCode() is not working.

Comment: From the documentation only a raw http response will be returned. You will have to parse it. `A successful response is any response received from the server that contains a status in the 2xx range. Note: Unlike the WLResponseListener.onSuccess(com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponse) method, this method is given the raw HTTP response. MobileFirst Platform does not attempt to read or process the content of this response in any way.`